# How to save the output result in file

Tags: perl, file-io

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
my@array = qw(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q  r s t u v w x y z);
my@array_a = @array[0..5];
my@array_b = @array[6..8];
my@array_c = @array[8..15];
my@array_d = @array[16..16];
my@array_e = @array[17..20];
my@array_f = @array[21..24];
my@array_g = @array[25..16];
print "first five string:",@array_a,"\n";
print @array_b,"\n";
print @array_c,"\n";
print @array_d,"\n";
print @array_e,"\n";
print @array_f,"\n";
print @array_g;
```

I have a above Perl script that Prints the results of the script on the terminal screen. Instead of having the information printed on the screen, I need it to save it to a text file.
i tried like my

```
 $filename = "/home/Ram/Desktop/Perl_file.txt";
open(my@array_a = @array[0..5], '>', $filename) or die "Could not open
+ file '$filename' $!";
print @array_a ;
close @array_a;
```

but it showing error like

first five string:abcdef ghi ijklmnop q rstu vwxy Can't use string ("6") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at array.pl line 22 (#1) (F) Only hard references are allowed by "strict refs". Symbolic references are disallowed. See perlref. Uncaught exception from user code: Can't use string ("6") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at array.pl line 22. at array.pl line 22.

Why it showing error? Please let me know

Comment: [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) => `open(my $fh, ">", "output.txt") or die $!;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not how you open a filehandle try:

```
open(my $fh,'>',$filename) or die "could not open $filename $!";
print $fh @array_a;
print $fh @array_b;
print $fh .......
```